# Error in SSIS doesn't go with new package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I was modifying a package, once I finished
I tried to start the package but an error showed up

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: The package failed to load due to error 0xC001001C "The object "%1" references ID "%2", but no object in the package has this ID.

> If the object "%1" was added to the package by a manual edit ensure that the referenced object with ID "%2" is also added to the package.".

> This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The package failed to load due to error 0xC001001C "The object "%1" references ID "%2", but no object in the package has this ID.  If the object "%1" was added to the package by a manual edit ensure that the referenced object with ID "%2" is also added to the package.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSPackagePersist100.LoadPackageFromXML(Object vSource, Boolean vbSourceIsLocation, IDTSEvents100 pEvents)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.LoadFromXML(String packageXml, IDTSEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package.LoadFromXML(String packageXml, IDTSEvents events)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project.LoadPackage(IProjectStorage storage, Package package, String streamName, IDTSEvents events)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.Load(IDTSEvents events)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.PackageItem.get_Package()
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.IncrementalBuildThroughObj(IOutputWindow outputWindow)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectBuilder.BuildIncremental(IOutputWindow outputWindow)           0
```

I tried with creating a new package but the moment I use UNION ALL control I get the same error

I started a new project and still the same problem

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of the union all and the package?